# How to hide Navigation bar when scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uinavigationbar

How do i hide or minimize the navigation bar when the user starts to scroll. For example, on instagram when you start to scroll through your news feed the nav bar minimizes.

Answer (score 0):

in ios8 you have property in navigation controller called:

[hidesBarsOnSwipe](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/hidesBarsOnSwipe)

in ios7 you can use method:

[setNavigationBarHidden:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setNavigationBarHidden:animated:)